# Destructor calls "Stopped working" error

Tags: c++, destructor

```
MainClass *mb[1];
Class1 *m1;     
cout << "Constructor type (1 - no parameters || 2 - with parameters): ";
    int choose;
    cin >> choose;
    if (choose == 1) {
        mb[1] = new Class1;
    }
    else if (choose == 2) {
        mb[1] = new Class1("Red", 1);
    }
    m1 = dynamic_cast<Class*>(mb[1]);
    m1->printEverything(); 
    getchar();
```

and after that Windows 10 throws me "Program1.exe stopped working".
Trying to add delete     mb[1]    , but no luck.

Destructor:

```
~Class() {
    cout << endl;
    getchar();
}
```

How can I delete derived class object?

Comment: Indexing in arrays is 0-based in C++. Use mb[0] to access the first element in mb[]. Your program is reading outside of the mb[] array, which is invalid.

Comment: Also, using an array with only one element is *extremely* unusual.

Comment: Your destructor should probably be virtual.

Answer (score 1):

Deallocation should be done by:

```
delete mb[0]
```

You should use mb[0] to access first element of array

Comment: Incorrect. `delete[]` is for deallocating memory allocated with `new []`. The OP's program nowhere does `new []`.

Comment: Correct now. But in the end you just copied my answer.

Comment: well you can say that, but i got to learn something new. thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the object in `mb[0]` (not `mb[1]`) because array indexing is 0-based in C and C++ and you only reserved space for one element in `mb`. Reading from or writing to mb[1] yields undefined behaviour in your program, typically resulting in a crash.

Deallocating your object must be done with `delete mb[0]`. **Not** with `delete[]` which is for deallocating memory allocated with `new []`.